# Removing a line from multiple files using grep & sed

Tags: shell, sed, grep

I have several source code files in a multi-level directory which contain forward declaration to a function

```
extern "C" void myPrintf(char *fmt, ...);
```

I want to remove this declaration from all the files.
I could do a grep which prints the line containing that declaration for all the files but not sure how to pipe it with sed to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `sed`

```
sed -i '/extern "C" void myPrintf(char \*fmt, \.\.\.);/d' *.c
```

If you want to perform this recursively, you have two options:

**With Bash 4.X**

```
shopt -s globstar; sed -i '/extern "C" void myPrintf(char \*fmt, \.\.\.);/d' **.c
```

**With find**

```
find /some/path -type f -name "*.c" -exec sed -i '/extern "C" void myPrintf(char \*fmt, \.\.\.);/d' {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks. I just kept "void myPrintf" in the search tag for it to find all the lines with different number of spaces in that statement

Answer (score 0):

#### Using `awk`:

```
awk '/void myPrintf/{next}1' oldfile > newfile
```

For ***batch updates***, you can do something like this -

```
find /path/to/files -type f -iname "*.c" | while read file; do
awk '/void myPrintf/{next}1' "$file" > "$file".new
mv "$file".new "$file"
done
```